Psych & Neurosci name change - some residuals
I would like to list remaining issues here below that need attention after our name change. I have added a new one open one below: 

The Site description now reads:   


Q&A for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science,
  psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry

In my opinion, this should be changed to 

Q&A for practitioners, researchers, and students in psychology & neuroscience, including the cognitive sciences and psychiatry.

Action: I was hoping @StevenJeuris can help out how to tackle this, if need be.
Status: pending

The new name is not reflected on Area 51.

Action: Update the name.
Status: Who do we contact about this?

New mod. Artem hasn't been on the site since November and I think this site needs a dedicated person that likes to volunteer to actively support new users, vote heavily (up votes, and at least as important, down voting), and actively support the above issues :) 

More issues here are more than welcomed. I can't turn this into a community wiki, but please comment below or grab me in chat and we'll fit it in.


Completed stuff, but please review if need be:

Site name is not updated in the Android app
Action: AliceD notified @AdamLear on this.
Status: Fixed by @AdamLear from the the SE mod team
Credits: @Ooker :)
Our new close-vote reason reads 


This question is not framed within the cognitive sciences. It is based on assumptions which are not made explicit, are not well-motivated (e.g., referenced), or are not held to be true within the cognitive sciences. For more information, see Why was my question closed as “not framed in cognitive sciences”?  

Action: Should we re-phrase this in terms of our new site name? If yes, I was hoping @StevenJeuris can help out how to tackle this, as this new vote reason was managed by him afaik.
Status: Fixed (by StevenJeuris? How did you do that so quickly?!)

The Neurobiology tag needed to be slaved to the Neuroscience tag, given that Neurosci is in our site name.
Action: Swap Neuroscience tag to be the master and Neurobiology to be the slave.
Status: completed
The tag description (For questions about the biology of the nervous system) needed editing to reduce the Biology emphasis.
Action: I edited the tag info to emphasize Neurobiology and de-emphasize the Biology part. Check it out here.
Status: completed


Hey - wait -- who fixed the close-vote reason? @StevenJeuris -- How did you do that?

I did not. :) Must have been some other mod, or the nice people of SE. :) I literally just heard about this awesome news!

I updated the on-topic description. Is this the one you were referring to @AliceD?

Oh the tour needs updating. I think we need to ping Ana or someone else for that one.

I double checked the close reason and noticed no change? I started a meta post to poll for new suggestions.

I would like to volunteer for new mod

I think @Chris would be a great mod.
